# UIToolBar BarButtonItem IBAction not working

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I've added a UIToolBar to an existing iPad application using IB.  I then connect it to the view controller with IB and verify that the connections exist.  However, when I click on the button, the corresponding code in the view controller is not executed.

I opened an empty project and followed the same procedure, and everything works as expected.

I'm curious if there are any ideas on what could be different in my existing project that is preventing the IBAction code from being executed?

I'm using XCode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0 (simulator) for development.

Any ideas are appreciated as I am really baffled!

Comment: I had the same problem. It turned out that I was using a UITapGestureRecognizer in the view that contained the toolbar and barbutton items. The UITapGestureRecognizer (single tap) was conflicting with the BarButtomItem actions. It appears the toolbar supports gestureRecognizers and this lead to the actions not working. Not sure if this is your problem but it correct my problem.

Answer (score 4):

As casillic mentioned in the comments, I had this problem due to the UITapGestureRecognizer I was using this to listen for when the user tapped the background so I could dismiss the keyboard if the user is editing a field.

The UITapGestureRecognizer conflicts with the toolbar and causes the code to not be executed when a toolbar item is selected - instead (in my case) it runs the "dismiss keyboard" code I have in my listener for the tab gesture.

To get around this, I added my gesture recogniser to the housing UIScrollView for the text inputs instead of the main containing view.

e.g:

replaced this:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

with this:

```
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

(scrollView is hooked up as an IBOutlet for the UIScrollView on my storyboards)